# Scapy - retrieving RSSI from WiFi packets

Tags: wifi, scapy, rssi

I'm trying to get RSSI or signal strength from WiFi packets.
I want also RSSI from 'WiFi probe requests' (when somebody is searching for a WiFi hotspots).

I managed to see it from kismet logs but that was only to make sure it is possible - I don't want to use kismet all the time.

For 'full time scanning' I'm using scapy. Does anybody know where can I find the RSSI or signal strength (in dBm) from the packets sniffed with scapy? I don't know how is the whole packet built - and there are a lot of 'hex' values which I don't know how to parse/interpret.

I'm sniffing on both interfaces - wlan0 (detecting when somebody connects to my hotspot), and mon.wlan0 (detecting when somebody is searching for hotspots).
Hardware (WiFi card) I use is based on Prism chipset (ISL3886). However test with Kismet was ran on Atheros (AR2413) and Intel iwl4965.

Edit1:

Looks like I need to access somehow information stored in PrismHeader:
http://trac.secdev.org/scapy/browser/scapy/layers/dot11.py
line 92 ?

Anybody knows how to enter this information?
packet.show() and packet.show2() don't show anything from this Class/Layer

Edit2:

After more digging it appears that the interface just isn't set correctly and that's why it doesn't collect all necessary headers.
If I run kismet and then sniff packets from that interface with scapy there is more info in the packet:

```
###[ RadioTap dummy ]###
  version= 0
  pad= 0
  len= 26
  present= TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna+b14
  notdecoded= '8`/\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x10\x02\x94\t\xa0\x00\xdb\x01\x00\x00'
  ...
```

Now I only need to set the interface correctly without using kismet.

Comment: Now decided in scapy 2.4.1+ or the github version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To summarize:

- signal strength was not visible because something was wrong in the way that 'monitor mode' was set (not all headers were passed/parsed by sniffers). This monitor interface was created by hostapd.
- now I'm setting monitor mode on interface with airmon-ng - tcpdump, scapy show theese extra headers.

**Edited: use scapy 2.4.1+ (or github dev version). Most recent versions now correctly decode the « notdecoded » part**

Comment: Yes I was. It's 'hidden' in the notdecoded part of the packet.
I'm extracting it with:
`sig_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-4:-3]))`

Comment: @kaczor1984 I tried: `sig_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-4:-3]))` and I get values like -69, -79, -81 etc. How do you interpret these values?

Comment: Just like you see them.
RSSI between -100 and 0 where 0 means that device was exactly at the place of 'detector' and -100 means very far away.
Of course I don't get usually values higher than ~-30.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a valuable scapy extension that improves `scapy.layers.dot11.Packet`'s parsing of present not decoded fields.

https://github.com/ivanlei/airodump-iv/blob/master/airoiv/scapy_ex.py

Just use:

```
import scapy_ex
```

And:

```
packet.show()
```

It'll look like this:

```
###[ 802.11 RadioTap ]###
  version   = 0
  pad       = 0
  RadioTap_len= 18
  present   = Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+Antenna+b14
  Flags     = 0
  Rate      = 2
  Channel   = 1
  Channel_flags= 160
  dBm_AntSignal= -87
  Antenna   = 1
  RX_Flags  = 0
```

Comment: You're best to clone the git repo and run the `import scapy_ex` from the airoiv directory as there other dependent files required by just scapy_ex.py (e.g. printer.py). Then it works nicely.

Comment: Not requires anymore as merged into the main repo

Comment: Doing this completely messed up the Dot11Beacon frame structure. Some tests like `pkt.haslayer` are no longer useful.

Answer (score 2):

For some reason the packet structure has changed. Now dBm_AntSignal is the first element in notdecoded.

I am not 100% sure of this solution but I used `sig_str = -(256 - ord(packet.notdecoded[-2:-1]))` to reach first element and I get values that seems to be `dBm_AntSignal`.

I am using `OpenWRT` in a `TP-Link MR3020` with extroot and Edward Keeble Passive Wifi Monitoring project with some modifications.

I use scapy_ex.py and I had this information:

```
802.11 RadioTap

  version   = 0

  pad       = 0

  RadioTap_len= 36

  present   = dBm_AntSignal+Lock_Quality+b22+b24+b25+b26+b27+b29

  dBm_AntSignal= 32

  Lock_Quality= 8
```

Comment: It's not. Every computer displays different information depending on the driver, the interface is using...

Answer (score 1):

If someone still has the same issue, I think I have found the solution:

I believe this is the right cut for the RSSI value:

```
sig_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-3:-2]))
```

and this one is for the noise level:

```
noise_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-2:-1]))
```

Comment: This may work on your machine, but isn’t a universal fix. Notdecoded is full of all tags added by your driver, meaning that you should check which flags are present. ([-4:-3] will not be the same on every computer). In most recent version of scapy (2.4.1+ or the github dev version, it is now properly decoded)

Answer (score 0):

The fact that it says "RadioTap" suggests that the device may supply [Radiotap headers](http://www.radiotap.org), not Prism headers, even though it has a Prism chipset.  [The p54 driver](http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/p54) appears to be a "SoftMAC driver", in which case it'll probably supply Radiotap headers; are you using the p54 driver or the older prism54 driver?

Answer (score 0):

I have similar problem, I set up the monitor mode with airmon-ng and I can see the dBm level in tcpdump but whenever I try the `sig_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-4:-3]))` I get -256 because the returned value from notdecoded in 0. Packet structure looks like this.

```
 version   = 0
 pad       = 0
 len       = 36
 present   = TSFT+Flags+Rate+Channel+dBm_AntSignal+b14+b29+Ext
 notdecoded= ' \x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x1f\x02\xed\x07\x05 
 .......
```