# How to Get the RSSI signal strength of an AP from a beacon frame? [scapy]

Tags: wifi, scapy

As far as i know, there's no such field in a Beacon frame that could directly indicate the signal strength of an Access Point in dbm. How this value is calculated in dbm?

**I am working in scapy**

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately RSSI is a property of the physical medium, while a beacon frame is a protocol element in the MAC layer. I.e. RSSI is how 'loud' the radio waves are to your receiving radio.

Unfortunately the question you have asked is something akin to "how do I get the voltage from an ethernet frame"....i.e. it doesn't really make sense.

To get the RSSI your hardware (i.e. the radio driver) has to include this information. I do not have any experience with scapy, but in wireshark this information is usually in the "radiotap header." E.g. if you look [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/t5/wireless-mobility-documents/802-11-sniffer-capture-analysis-physical-layer/ta-p/3115883) you can see that the RSSI information is in a separate section the 'beacon frame'.

Perhaps this question might contain answers: [RadioTap headers in scapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35851539/radiotap-headers-in-scapy)