# Scapy Sniffer - Receiving RSSI

Tags: wireless, scapy, rssi, sniffer

I am interested in getting the RSSI values if APs using a scapy sniffer. I am using `sig_str = -(256-ord(packet.notdecoded[-4:-3]))`
 to get the RSSI values. However, I am getting -256 for all the APs. The notdecoded part is then 0. Could someone please help me figure this one out?

PS: I have already referenced this relevant post.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/34118234/4804221

TIA!

Comment: Did you use the monitor mode? Or you found a decision?

Comment: I used the monitor mode. However, I still have not found a solution to this problem.

Comment: Did you use wireshark on monitor interface to check rssi?

Answer (score 0):

### Prerequisite

Assuming the interface is in monitor mode, and correct channel assigned.
Following example configures `iface=wlan0` to `monitor mode` and listens to `channel=6`

```sh
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 down
$ sudo iw dev wlan0 set type monitor
$ sudo ip link set wlan0 up
$ sudo iw dev wlan0 set channel 6
```

### Python3

RSSI from a packet can be earned by `dBm_AntSignal` if `RadioTap` header is correctly sniffed together.

```py
from scapy.all import RadioTap
from scapy.all import sniff

# sniff a packet from the interface
pkt = sniff(iface="wlan0", count=1)
pkt = pkt[0]

# getting the RSSI
radiotap = pkt.getlayer(RadioTap)
rssi = radiotap.dBm_AntSignal
print("RSSI={}".format(rssi)) # RSSI=-84
```

### Python2

Seems like `dBm_AntSignal` is not working on python2 scapy, following example will work.

```py
extra = pkt.notdecoded
rssi = -(256-ord(extra[-4:-3]))
```

Hope this helps.